# jQuery is removing wrong table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to remove 1st column of my html table by referencing this site: [**Link**](http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/jquery-remove-table-column-by-column-number/).

But when i clicked on it, 2nd column of my table get removed. And on second click, 3rd column gets removed. And on further clicks, nothing happens. Below you can check my html and javascript, it's plain simple but i'm really confused about the result.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            function deleteFirstColumn(){
                //$('table tr').find('td:eq(1),th:eq(1)').remove();

                //remove the 1st column
                $('table tr').find('td:eq(1),th:eq(1)').remove();

                //remove the 2nd column
                //$('table tr').find('td:eq(1),th:eq(1)').remove();
            }
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <button type="button" onclick="deleteFirstColumn()"> delete first column</button>

        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>column 1</td>
                <td>column 2</td>
                <td>column 3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>c 1</td>
                <td>c 2</td>
                <td>c 3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>c 1</td>
                <td>c 2</td>
                <td>c 3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which is correct, since indices in JavaScript start with `0`:

```
$('table tr').find('td:eq(0),th:eq(0)').remove();  // remove 1st column
```

After each click your jQuery selector finds the first column from what is left in the table, so after 3 clicks you will remove all columns from the table.

Comment: _since indices in JavaScript start with 0_ what about nth-child's indices..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy This is not JavaScript. Read in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/): *Because jQuery's implementation of `:nth-` selectors is strictly derived from the CSS specification, the value of `n` is "1-indexed", meaning that the counting starts at 1*.

Comment: Alright, :eq is a Jquery made selector.. I just confused at that point.

Answer (score 1):

[**`.eq()`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) works with `zero` based index. In other words, the lower bound that we consider while using that function is `zero`,

Try,

```
 $('table tr').find('td:eq(0),th:eq(0)').remove();
```